# Symfony 2.3.6 and Sonata Admin Bundle : Empty dashboard and no errors

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I've been looking for what is going wrong for days now; I followed the documentation from the sonata website and repeated it several times, but my dashboard is still empty.  After writing my `AdminClass` and `Services` (and setup the `config.yml`), I regenerate entities and updated my schema, but Sonata created a table in my DB for entities that I wanted to be in `admin`.

Here is my code for `App/Config/Config.yml` ( top of file for imports )

```
imports:
- { resource: parameters.yml }
- { resource: security.yml }
- { resource: @materniteamAppBundle/Resources/config/admin.yml }
- { resource: @materniteamUserBundle/Resources/config/admin.yml }
```

`App/Config/Config.yml` ( bottom of file with sonata config )

```
# FOS USER
   fos_user:
       db_driver:     orm
       firewall_name: main
      user_class:    materniteam\UserBundle\Entity\User

# ADMIN SONATA
   sonata_block:
        default_contexts: [cms]
        blocks:
        sonata.admin.block.admin_list:
        contexts:   [admin]

            sonata.block.service.text:
            sonata.block.service.action:
            sonata.block.service.rss:

 sonata_admin:
     title: Materniteam
         security:
            handler: sonata.admin.security.handler.role
            acl_user_manager: fos_user.user_manager
```

Here is my Admin Class for entity Contact `//src/APP/APPBundle/Admin/ContactAdmin.php`:

```
<?php

   namespace materniteam\AppBundle\Admin;

   use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\Admin;
   use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper;
   use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\DatagridMapper;
   use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;

  class ContactAdmin extends Admin
  {
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
   {
    $formMapper
        ->with('General')
            ->add('prenom')
            ->add('nom')
            ->add('adresse')
            ->add('codePostal')
            ->add('ville')
        ->end()
    ;
}

protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{
    $listMapper
        ->addIdentifier('Nom')
        ->add('prenom')
        ->add('adresse')
        ->add('codePostal')
        ->add('ville')
        ->add('_action', 'actions', array(
            'actions' => array(
            'view' => array(),
            'edit' => array(),
            'delete' => array(),
            )
        ))
    ;
}

protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
{
    $datagridMapper
        ->add('prenom')
        ->add('nom')
        ->add('adresse')
    ;
}
}
?>
```

and finally here is my service call `//src/APP/APPBundle/Resources/config/admin.yml`

```
services:
materniteam.app.admin.contact:
    class: materniteam\AppBundle\Admin\ContactAdmin
    tags:
        - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: "App", label: "Contact" }
    arguments: [ null, materniteam\AppBundle\Entity\Contact, SonataAdminBundle:CRUD ]
```

like I said, I have no errors, but the dashboard is still not listing my entities. If you need more code, just ask  and I'll edit this message.

If any Sonata group member is reading this :

PLEASE UPDATE YOUR DOCUMENTATION !!!

Comment: You should move your answer into answer. Btw, did you specify `access_decision_manager:
        strategy: unanimous` as per http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/security.html#id1 ? With `role` voter that should work, unless you have logged in with non-super-admin user and did not enable LIST right for that Admin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the problem occurs with the security part of sonata.

In my config.yml , i set the security of sonata with the following values :

```
    security:
    handler: sonata.admin.security.handler.role
```

which tells sonata to use security based on user roles ( which i think is great )
I succeeded to see my entities in sonata by replacing the handler by the following

```
    security:
    handler: sonata.admin.security.handler.noop
```

which tells sonata to use Symfony based security. ( i had btw to promote my user to ROLE_ADMIN to continue accessing sonata dashboard )

Answer (score 0):

Try this in sonata admin block

```
   sonata_block:
     default_contexts: [cms]
     blocks:
       sonata.admin.block.admin_list:
            contexts:   [admin]
       sonata.block.service.text:
       sonata.block.service.action:
       sonata.block.service.rss:
```