# Dashboard and login page complete blank sonata admin bundle

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, sonata-admin, sonata-user-bundle

About 3 days ago I updated my composer to install another bundle.

Since then my /admin/login and /admin/dashboard routes are complete blank (a blank page html)

No errors, no warnings, nothing.

If I remove Roles I can access entites admin page directly (like /admin/product/edit...). But login and dashboard still blank.

I reinstalled bundles any times and I really don't know what I can do now.

Here is my files:

```
#app/config/config.yml

imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: @VisaoAdminBundle/Resources/config/admin.yml }

framework:
    #esi:             ~
    translator:      { fallback: pt_BR }
    secret:          %secret%
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: %kernel.debug%
    form:            ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
        #assets_version: SomeVersionScheme
    default_locale:  pt_BR
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:         ~
    fragments:       ~

# fos-user
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User
    group:
        group_class: Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\Group
        group_manager: sonata.user.orm.group_manager
    service:
        user_manager: sonata.user.orm.user_manager

sonata_user:
    manager_type: orm # can be orm or mongodb

# sonata-admin
sonata_admin:
    title:  Visão Brindes e Impressos
    title_logo: bundles/visaomain/images/logo_visao_brindes_admin.png

# sonata-block    
sonata_block:
    default_contexts: [cms]
    blocks:
        # Enable the SonataAdminBundle block
        sonata.admin.block.admin_list:
            contexts:   [admin]
        sonata.block.service.text:
        sonata.block.service.action:
        sonata.block.service.rss:
        # Your other blocks

# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            %kernel.debug%
    strict_variables: %kernel.debug%

# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    debug:          %kernel.debug%
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        [ ]
    #java: /usr/bin/java
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        #closure:
        #    jar: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/compiler.jar
        #yui_css:
        #    jar: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   %database_driver%
        host:     %database_host%
        port:     %database_port%
        dbname:   %database_name%
        user:     %database_user%
        password: %database_password%
        charset:  UTF8
        types:
            json: Sonata\Doctrine\Types\JsonType
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver, add the path in parameters.yml
        # e.g. database_path: %kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3
        # path:     %database_path%
    orm:
       auto_mapping: true

# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: %mailer_transport%
    host:      %mailer_host%
    username:  %mailer_user%
    password:  %mailer_password%
    spool:     { type: memory }
```

Thank you!

Comment: Don't forget to add ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN to your user role in the security configuration.

Comment: Have u done cache clear ?

Comment: Cache clear ok. ROLES too. I can see another pages (/admin/product/edit...) only when I am logged. I do this in login page of FOSUser (/login instead /admin/login). I think the problem can be some twig template of login and dashboard sonata.

Comment: Possible duplicate ? 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19445451/symfony-2-3-6-and-sonata-admin-bundle-empty-dashboard-and-no-errors

Comment: @Charles-AntoineFournel I did what the author suggested. But I think my problem is different. He can't see the entities in dashboard. I can't see everything. Like my page is a <html></html> whithout any content.

Comment: This looks like you are some error in your code. Did you check out your error.log file in /var/log/?